# How to get list of site collections on SharePoint 2013 using SharePoint PnP

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Try to use SharePoint PnP to get all the sites on a SharePoint 2013 server.

From central administration, I can view all site collections as

```
/
/people/A
/people/B
...
```

The site urls are like

```
https://people-hr.mycompany.com
https://people-hr.mycompany.com/A/JohnAllen
https://people-hr.mycompany.com/A/SamAdams
https://people.hr.mycompany.com/B/JamesBell
...
```

Using

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://products.mycompany.com" -Credentials (Get-Credential)
or
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://products.mycompany.com/A/JohnAllen" -Credentials (Get-Credential)
```

I can get to the root site or a subsite. But there are so many sites. I need to get all the sites so I can iterate them to do some data maintenance.

I tried to use Get-PnPSite and Get-PnPSubWebs (with Recurse), but they failed to return all the sites.

Answer (score 0):

Get-PnPTenantSite will return all the site collections. in order to iterate through each, Try this:

```
     $cred = Get-Credential

    Connect-PnPOnline "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com" -Credentials $cred
    $SiteCollections = Get-PnPTenantSite
    foreach ($SiteCollection in $SiteCollections)
      {
          Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteCollection.Url -Credentials $cred
          Get-PnPSubWebs
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the command `Get-PnPTenantSite` to list all site collections.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnptenantsite?view=sharepoint-ps